# How to find the width of the child ul li a

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have following unordered list wrapped in a div as below

```
    <div id="menuwrapper">
    <ul>
     <li>home
           <ul>
             <li><a>anchor1</a></li>
             <li><a>anchor2</a></li>
             <li><a>anchor3</a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>

    <li>school</li>
    <li>college</li>
    </ul>  
    </div>
```

I need to find width of each anchors that is anchor1,anchor2,anchor3 tags width on hover of home.
I have the following code which seems not to work

```
    $(function () {

      $("#menuwrapper ul li").hover(function () {
      var maxWidth = 0;
      $(this).find("ul li a").each(function () {

          if (this.width > maxWidth)
              maxWidth = this.width;
      });

      $("#menuwrapper ul li ul li a").css("width", maxWidth);
  });
 });
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var maxWidth = 0;
    $("#menuwrapper ul li:first-child").hover(function() {
        var $anchors = $(this).find("ul li a");
        $anchors.each(function() {    
            if ($(this).width() > maxWidth) {
                maxWidth = $(this).width();
            }
        });
        $anchors.width(maxWidth);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$this` should be `$(this)`. Or you need to set `var $this = $(this);` in scope.

Comment: i dont think its the problem,it doesnt even go upto $(this.width....It couldnot execute the "$(this).find("ul li a").each(function ()" line

Comment: Why is it only checking the heights on the hover?

Comment: And this will set the maxWidth to 'that' li's submenu, but then it will revalidate every time you hover on a different menu. Did you want all menus to be the same, or different?

Comment: basically i want to set width of the sub menu based on maxwidth anchor,so on hover i am checking the anchor which has maximum width and then setting that maximum width to the entire submenu.Hope i am clear..?

Comment: why the hover then? is this menu supposed to appear/disappear?

Comment: yes menu appears and disappears.Its a navigation menu which appears on the top of every page in website

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9560/discussion-between-bhargav-and-s-kiers)

Comment: please let me know if u could come to chat

Comment: sorry I had to run. I am posting a second solution

Answer (score 1):

This does your hover and setting the width

```
$(function () {
    // First we detect and set the widths, then we hide the subMenu
    var $maxWidth = 0,
        $anchors = $("#menuwrapper ul li ul li a");
    $anchors.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.width() > $maxWidth)
        {
            $maxWidth = $this.width();
         }
    });
    $anchors.css('width', $maxWidth)
      .closest('ul')
      .hide();

    // Then we add the hover actions
    $("#menuwrapper ul li").hover(
        function()
        {
            $(this).find("ul").slideDown();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).find("ul").slideUp();
        }
    );
});
```

This could be optimized better, but I thought this way is most explanatory.

Comment: This allows your structure to include multiple submenus. If you want only have one, then alpaca lips' 'li:first-child' would be more effective.